# Windbg !address command result

Tags: debugging, windbg

Using Windbg, we can find some info about an `!address`. One of the info us Usage.
What is the difference between: `RegionUsageIsVAD`, or `RegionUsageHeap`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Please check out this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2009/02/03/net-memory-leak-to-dispose-or-not-to-dispose-that-s-the-1-gb-question.aspx) which describes those stats. Basically, `RegionUsageIsVAD` is details about virtual memory allocations. Whilst `RegionUsageHeap` is information about allocations in the heap.

Comment: Concluding, RegionUsageIsVAD stands for virtual allocs and  RegionUsageHeap for heap allocs.